# Robot Framework - TeamCity integration - Tests tab

Tags: xml, testing, teamcity, reporting, robotframework

I would like to include my Robot Framework generated xml test results in TeamCity Tests tab (when checking a build).
Do you know any standard plugin for it?
I have tried with Build Feature functionality with XML report without any luck.

Should I write something to send TC service messages or there is an easy way?
Thank you.

Comment: My team uses a listener to send service messages. It's pretty straight-forward, and the interface is fairly well documented by TeamCity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it with using the following:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

I couldn`t put anything to the output (I didn`t find how in documentation). print("Sth") didn`t work. However I wrote to a file and printed it out in another TC step.

Comment: That is old documentation for the listener interface. The correct URL is http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Comment: Thank you, I updated it. The thing which I needed was same in both and it is working fine.